# How to log colored messages with grunt.log

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I want to log a warning, yellow message, with Grunt, when running a specific task.

Currently I use `grunt.log.subhead` to output bold font, but it does no take to much attention.

```
grunt.log.subhead 'You may want to use --sourceMaps option'
```

Comment: Better use something like https://github.com/Marak/colors.js

Comment: Grunt *is actually* using [colors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/colors) and by looking at the two great answers below, it was also the case at the time the question was asked. The funny syntax used to format text is colors' "super nifty way" which modifies `String.prototype` to add properties such as `.green` or `.bold`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
grunt.log.writeln('You may want to use --sourceMaps option'['yellow'].bold);
```

The grunt API documentation for log does not mention how to do this. I found it in a set of slides here:
http://slides.com/joshschumacher/grunt-logging#/

Comment: You can also use:


`grunt.log.write('Path: '.cyan);`
`grunt.log.writeln(path);`

Comment: Also, if you are concatenating strings (i.e. using variables in strings), enclose everything in parenthesis first: `grunt.log.writeln( ( 'concatenated ' + variable + ' and string need parenthesis' ).yellow )`

Answer (score 18):

From the slides mentioned by @jon, valid colors are:

```
var colors = ['white', 'black', 'grey', 'blue', 'cyan', 'green', 'magenta', 'red', 'yellow', 'rainbow'];

colors.forEach(function (color) {
  grunt.log.writeln('testing'[color]);
  grunt.log.writeln('testing bold'[color].bold);
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to grab the colors array from grunt's object?